# Button visibility dependent of field security profile

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to hide/disable a button dependent of the users field security profile. I thought of a javascript webresource, used in the customizations.xml file, that returns true or false if the executing user owns the specified field security profile. Is there any possibility to retrieve these information using JavaScript or is there another way?

I tried to get the value of the secured field, but it always returns null if the user has the role and field is empty and if the user not has the role.

```
var securedField = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('secured_field').getValue();
console.log(securedField);
```

User doesnt have the security profile -> `null`

User has the security profile, field empty -> `null`

User has the security profile, field has value -> `value`

Comment: Have a look at this: http://mileyja.blogspot.com/2011/10/get-all-field-level-permissions-for.html. The Soap Logger will be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the user roles:
You can try:

```
var UserRoles = Xrm.Page.context.getUserRoles();
```

Also see the more complex query route:

http://blogs.infinite-x.net/2010/11/16/retreiving-user-roles-in-crm-2011/

This works really well though^^

To get privileges on attributes:

```
var attributePrivileges = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(attributeName).getUserPrivilege();
console.log('Can read: ' + attributePrivileges.canRead);
console.log('Can create: ' + attributePrivileges.canCreate);
console.log('Can update: ' + attributePrivileges.canUpdate);
```

[MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334409.aspx#BKMK_getUserPrivilege)

Comment: Also: http://lakshmanindian.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/check-user-security-role-in-crm-2011-using-jscript/

Comment: I know that you can retrieve security roles of an user, but I need to get the field security profiles.

Comment: getUserPrivilege?
-
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("attributeschema").getUserPrivilege().canCreate
-
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("attributeschema").getUserPrivilege().canUpdate
-
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("attributeschema").getUserPrivilege().canRead